# Getting "Unable to cast ..SQLExpression.SQLParameterExpression" to SQLExpression.SQLConstantExpression" conversion from LINQ to SQL Query Core 3.1

Tags: .net, asp.net-core-3.1, .net-core-3.1

I am migrating application from net core 2.2 to 3.1. In that I am using ToSql extension method. This method throws Casting exception message, unable to cast SQLParameterExpression" to SQLExpression.SQLConstantExpression. This happens when I pass any list of value like- var city = new[]{"a","b"}; querableVal= querableVal.Where(u=> city.contains(c.Name)); querableVal.ToSQL();
In this it is throwing exception. But, if I pass,  querableVal= querableVal.Where(u=> new[]{"a","b"}.contains(c.Name)); querableVal.ToSQL(); then it works. I need any extension method, which generates SQL query from linq like -
Linq Expression -
_dbMOdel.City.AsQuerable().Where(a=>listData.contains(a.Name)); // listData is List of string having city names

Expected Result - SELECT * FROM City WHERE City_Name IN ("abc", "xyz", "pqr")

please help at the earliest.

Comment: Can you please format the code so that it is more readable?